# Dual boot missing ubuntu 12.04 LTS ,now only Windows is directly starting?

Tags: partitioning

Previously i have window7 and ubuntu with dual boot. But now window 7 is directly starting there is no option for ubuntu (no boot manager) but i checked via live cd ubuntu partiton ext4 is there and all files also but it directly not starting and windows also not determine that partition or ubuntu boot loader entry ?

Answer (score 1):

Dowload **Easybcd software** it is free for home user install it open it you will see add new entry click on it go to linux tab add entry click on edit boot menu select the appropriate timeout option and save setting

Comment: thanks , its working with some additional efforts, before that i am not sure its perfectly working with another type partition .